# How to update and delete a data in a list according to it's document id - flutter, firebase 2021

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete and update a list of details in flutter. For that i used `doc('document_id')` which was given as a solution in another stackoverflow question. I tried some another solutions given in stacker flow too. But nothing fork for me. But if I give a specific documentID I am able to delete that. Also how can I pass the selected data to update page too.

```
class addressProfile extends StatefulWidget {
const addressProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_addressProfileState createState() => _addressProfileState();
}

class _addressProfileState extends State<addressProfile> {
  var Default = 'unDefault';

delete() async {
try {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("address")
      .doc('document_id')
      .delete();
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    title: Text(
      'My Addresses',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back_ios,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profilePage');
      },
    ),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    children: [
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("address").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 700,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      return Container(
                        child: Card(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(x['firstName']),
                                    Text(' '),
                                    Text(x['lastName']),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text(""),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(x['primaryPhone']),
                                    Text(" / "),
                                    Text(x['secondaryPhone']),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text(''),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(x['address1']),
                                    Text(', '),
                                    Text(x['address2']),
                                    Text(', '),
                                    Text(x['city']),
                                    Text(', '),
                                    Text(x['region']),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Divider(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: Radio(
                                          value: 'default',
                                          groupValue: Default,
                                          onChanged: (String? val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              if (val != null)
                                                Default = val;
                                            });
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text("Default"),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                                      child: Align(
                                        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            if (snapshot.data!.docs.length >
                                                1) {
                                              delete();
                                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                msg:
                                                    "Address deleted successfully",
                                                toastLength:
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                                gravity:
                                                    ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                                                textColor: Colors.black,
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Colors.green.shade400,
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                msg:
                                                    "Main address cannot be deleted",
                                                toastLength:
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                                gravity:
                                                    ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                                                textColor: Colors.black,
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Colors.green.shade400,
                                              );
                                            }
                                          },
                                          label: Text('Delete'),
                                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                              fixedSize: Size(90, 20),
                                              primary: Colors.red.shade500,
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 5,
                                              ),
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          10))),
                                          icon: Icon(
                                              Icons.delete_outline_sharp),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14),
                                      child: Align(
                                        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (builder) =>
                                                    updateAddress(),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                          label: Text('Update'),
                                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                              fixedSize: Size(90, 20),
                                              primary:
                                                  Colors.green.shade500,
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 5,
                                              ),
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          10))),
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
      Align(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/addNewAddress');
          },
          child: Text(
            "Add New Address",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              letterSpacing: 2,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              fixedSize: Size(250, 40),
              primary: Colors.green.shade500,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 50,
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

This is so far I did. Please help me to continue.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you have saved the data. But I got an issue like this and what I did was, I added a variable as "id" to database while saving the data. There is an auto generated id plugin for flutter (`nanoid`). You can add that and save the data as following.

```
var id = nanoid(10) //10 is the length of the id. You can give as you wish

create() async {
  try {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection("address")
       .doc(id)
       .set({
         "id":id,
         //other inputs 
       });
 } catch (e) {
   print(e);
 }
}
```

Then you can use that id as a key to update ad delete.
For example according to you code to delete you can use like this in the `onPress(){}` of delete button,

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("address").doc(x['id']).delete();`

So the data related to id will be deleted.
Also better to use proper name rather than "x".

Comment: @Mofidul Islam 's answer is the better and easiest option. But not deleting my answer because it might help someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this

```
delete(String docId) async {
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("address")
          .doc(docId)
          .delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Your delete function call

```
delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id);
```

Update document

```
void update(String docId){
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("address").doc(docId) .update({"field1":"fieldValue1","field2":"fieldValue2"});
}
```

Let me know if you find any issues in comment

Comment: Thankyou so much. This is the the easiest solution I found. Can I also know how I can pass the data for updating.  Like when I select the update button for a data in the list, how can I pass the relevant data to update form. Can I do it in the on press of update?

Comment: You can update as well like this  FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("address")
          .doc(docId)
          .update({"field1":"fieldValue1","field2":"fieldValue2"});

Comment: First I want to pass the value for view page to update page. When I select the OnPress() of update button in this page, it need to navigate to Update page. They I need to show the relevant fields of this id in text field. There I need to be able to update